# Storing user ID and password globally?

Tags: swift2

I'm trying to create a login process by sending a POST request to a web server. The post string contains the username and the password, which the user types in a textfield.

As a response I get the user ID and a SHA1 encrypted password. Since I need both of them to access other pages on the server, I have to store them globally in my project.

So my question is, what is the best way to do so? Should I create a class USER, where I store those items as properties?

Comment: You can check out the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It is implemented using `static` variables in a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using 2 different ways,

01:-

```
      let Id = username.text
      let password = password.text
      let displayName = display.text

      // TO STROE DATA
      var prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
      prefs.setInteger(Id!, forKey: "USERID") // FOR INTEGER VALUES
      prefs.setInteger(password!, forKey: "USERPASSWORD")
      prefs.setObject(displayName!, forKey: "DISPLAYNAME") // FOR STRING VALUES
      prefs.synchronize()

      // FOR GET STORED DATA 

      let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
      Id.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERID") as? Int
      JId.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERJID") as? Int
      displayName.text = prefs.valueForKey("DISPLAYNAME") as? String
```

when you log out or if you want to clear the stored data, just use

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!)
```

02:-

1. First create a global class,

   ```
   import Foundation


   class User {
   class var sharedInstance: User {
   struct Static {
       static var instance: User?
       static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
   }

   dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
       Static.instance = User()
   }

   return Static.instance!
   ```

   }

   ```
   var userId: Int?
   var VId: Int?
   var isHome: Int?
   ```

   }

then store data in the class that you want

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

  let user = User.sharedInstance


 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {


            self.user.userId = Id
            self.user.VId = VacancyId


        }

    }



 }
```

Then retrieve data :-

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController { 

  let user = User.sharedInstance


            mylabel.text = self.user.userId 
            mylabael2.text = self.user.VId




 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really store details like these in the keychain. You also don't really want these details held in memory more than necessary as that makes them easier to steal. You can create a class which is a wrapper around this keychain access and whenever requested you can extract the values from the keychain (so if the keychain isn't accessible because the user has locked it they won't be available).